# not able to navigate to new record page

Tags: lightning-web-components, navigationmixin.navigate

Onclick of button in LWC i want to redirect to new Account creation page .But when i try the below code i am able to redirect to list view bot to the record creation page

LWC HTML :

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Navigate To Record ">
        <lightning-button label=" New Account" onclick={navigateToNewAccount}></lightning-button>
        <lightning-button label="Account Recent list View" onclick={navigateToList}></lightning-button>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import {LightningElement,wire} from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin} from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class Navexamples extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

    navigateToNewAccount() {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__objectPage',
            attributes: {
                objectApiName: 'Account',
                actionName: 'new'
            },
        });
    }
   

    navigateToList() {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__objectPage',
            attributes: {
                objectApiName: 'Account',
                actionName: 'list'
            },
            state: {
                filterName: 'Recent'
            },
        });
    }  
}
```

Anyone can help me on this .

Comment: This seems to be correct, is there any error? Does the user have permission to create Accounts?

Comment: yeah User has the permission . Its not redirected

Comment: I tested the same component in App Builder and it worked. Can I ask you where are you embedding the component (Flow, Visualforce, App Builder, etc)?